# unable to set innodb_directories in mysql5.7.28

Tags: mysql-5.7

I m unable to set innodb_directories in mysql5.7.28. Below the error

```
enter code here
cat /etc/my.cnf
innodb_directories="/u01/tablespaces/"

cat /varlog/mysql.log
2019-11-03T06:14:54.567062Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'innodb_directories=/u01/tablespaces/'
2019-11-03T06:14:54.567104Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: That was added in MySQL 8

Comment: is it. Thanks a lot